# Compute and Analyze the run-time

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, analysis

```
public static long Compute(int x){
    long count = 0;
    if(x==1)
        return count=1;
    else if(x==3)
        for(int i =0;i<x;i++){
            count+=i;
    }
    else if (x==5)
            for(int j=0;j<x;j++)
                for(int k=0;j<=x;k++)
                     return +=(i*j);
                }
            }
    return result;
}
```

Im trying to understand how to solve each of the statements to formulate the run-time T(n). I have 2 if statements and a for-loop and a nested for-loop. My answer here is O(n^2).

Comment: What are you trying to compute ?

Comment: @EricWang the time-complexity, big-O

Comment: The variable `count` can be removed, it's barely used `return count=1;` can be replaced by `return 1;` and in the for loop `for(int i =0;i<x;i++){ count+=i; }` the variable `count` is increased but not used anymore

Comment: What is that : `return +=(i*j);` ?

Comment: Complexity can be O(1). The values of `x` is known in each loops (`if (x == ...)`) and therefore, this can be calculated without loops

Answer (score 1):

f = O(g) means that there's a N and c, so that n>N implies f(n) <= c * g(n). (I assume f and g are non-negative).

The code takes constant time for x>5. So it's O(1).